Keycloak: Retrieve Client Scopes Mapped to a Specific Role
In my Keycloak setup, I have several client scopes and roles:

Scopes represent specific permissions (e.g., entity.create,
entity.view, entity.delete).
Roles aggregate these permissions (e.g., the "Guest" role maps to
entity.view, and the "Administrator" role maps to entity.create,
entity.view, and entity.delete).

Now I need to get the list of the scopes assigned to a specific role, for example the "Guest", to present it in the frontend and allow the user to map new scopes or remove mapped scopes.
There's a keycloak endpoint to receive this list? In my understanding, the only way to get this information is to get the entire list of the client scopes using GET /admin/realms/{realm}/client-scopes, and then iterate on each scope id using GET /admin/realms/{realm}/client-scopes/{client-scope-id}/scope-mappings/clients/{client} to check if the role is in the mapped roles. But this is totally inefficient...
I'm struggling with this for a while now... I hope there's a solution.
Thank you all.
Copilot suggested me to use the endpoint GET admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-id}/scope-mappings, but this endpoint seems to return just the mapping between the client and the roles, and there's no reference to the scopes (despite the endpoint name...)

Unfortunately, Keycloak doesn’t provide a direct endpoint to list scopes assigned to a specific role. However, you can use the GET /admin/realms/{realm}/roles-by-id/{role-id} endpoint to fetch details about a role. If the role is composite, the response will include all associated roles and permissions (scopes). Alternatively, you can use GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-id}/scope-mappings to retrieve all scope mappings for a client and cross-reference them with your role.

Hello,
Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately your advice doesn't seem to apply to my case.
I tried GET /admin/realms/{realm}/roles-by-id/{role-id}, and the returned role doesn't contain the associated scopes, but just the associated roles (if it's composite).
Then I tried also GET /admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-id}/scope-mappings, but it seems to return always an empty list, don't know why.
In the end my solution was to create a custom attribute in the role and list there the scopes. I don't like it so much... but it seems to work. Until when I will find a better solution :)
